# Sum Grouped Data in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to SUM grouped data in a report but can't figure out a way to do it.

My data looks something like this:
[image]

I am trying to get value 4 in Grand Total which would show the number of orders on different schedules. Simple count would count all the detail lines giving me value 8, count distinct would give me value 3 as there are 3 unique orders.
Is there a way to sum subgroup totals (which are calculated as count distinct per schedule).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a field to the dataset (either in the query, or as a calculated field in the dataset) called Schedule-Order, with values like "1234-1111", "1234-2222".

Then you can do a count distinct on this field.

Comment: Yes, this will work, thank you. I was trying to achieve it using CountRows("GroupbyCategory") but couldn't get the syntax right. Any ideas?